# Flutter webview unable to upload(choose) image in Adroid but working fine in iOS

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-3.0

I'm using [webview_flutter 3.0.4 version](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)  , Also give access permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

After run the app device has taken permission. Web view image uploading working fine in iOS, but when I'm trying to upload image in android it's not making any response.

This my simple code

```
body: WebView(
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    userAgent: 'OFFICIAL_APPLICATION',
                    initialUrl:"https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_file_upload_button.asp",
                    onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) {
                        this.webViewController = webViewController;
              }, 
    )
```

[image]

How I can upload image in webview using package webview_flutter ? Do we need more settings ?

Comment: Any news? Facing the same issue

Comment: Please also edit your question and add the permission requests section of your app